# Multiplicação de campos no Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Tenho o seguinte treco de código:

```
const buys = await Buy.findAll({
  where: {
    account_id: req.params.id,
  },
  attributes: ['id', 'account_id', 'buy_value', 'quantity'],
});

return res.json(buys);
```

Que me retorna o seguinte JSON:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "account_id": 3,
    "buy_value": "49521.00",
    "quantity": 2
}
```

Gostaria de retornar dentro do mesmo JSON, um campo `teste` que multiplica os campos `buy_value` e `quantity`. Como posso fazer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira. Utilizei o `literal` do Sequelize:

```
import { literal } from 'sequelize';

const buys = await Buy.findAll({
      where: {
        account_id: req.params.id,
      },
      attributes: [
        'id',
        'account_id',
        'buy_value',
        'quantity',
        [literal('buy_value * quantity'), 'test_field'],
      ],
    });

    return res.json(buys);
```